# Export PFX with proper KeySpec (Windows Server 2012 R2)

Tags: pfx, code-signing-certificate

If have a certificate in my store and I checked with `certutil` that `KeySpec` is set to `AT_SIGNATURE` (I had to reimport it accordingly). Now whenever I export the certificate (via `MMC` or `PowerShell`) the `KeySpec` is set back to `AT_KEYEXCHANGE`. How can I change that?

Comment: How do you verify the KeySpec? This works at least for me: Import the cert at keySpec 1 into local store in user space. Open mmc and export the cert again with private key. Voila - KeySpec 2. To check the KeySpec I used `certutil -v export.pfx > log.txt` And `log.txt` contains both then `AT_SIGNATURE` and `AT_KEYEXCHANGE`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/technical-reference/ad-fs-and-keyspec-property):

> A KeySpec value of 1, or AT_KEYEXCHANGE, can be used for signing and
> encryption. A value of 2, or AT_SIGNATURE, is only used for signing.

When you import the certificate using [certutil](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html) you can specify that it's only set to `AT_SIGNATURE`, if you want that restriction applied, e.g.

`certutil -p SOME_PASSWORD -importPFX .\mycert.pfx AT_SIGNATURE`

If you don't specify `AT_SIGNATURE` and it's imported with `AT_KEYEXCHANGE` then you should be able to use the cert for signing AND encryption.

To check the KeySpec of a certificate you can use `certutil -dump -v .\mycert.pfx`, or other params to get the cert from the local store, and then search in the results for "KeySpec".